# What does expression "speak up to the point" mean?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

I just used the expression *speak up to the point* as a way of saying:

- *Express without blathering*
- *Get directly to the actualy point*

Have I used this expression correctly? Are there any other better expressions suited to this meaning?

Comment: To "speak to the point" is to address the actual (no y) point under discussion rather than digressing. To "speak up" is either to speak more loudly or assertively. "Speak up to the point" isn't a common usage and sounds awkward, but if someone said it to me I would interpret it as "speak until you reach the point, then stop" -- which is not what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be relevant and to the point:

[CEPR](http://www.cepr.net/index.php/blogs/beat-the-press/the-washington-post-wants-seniors-to-take-a-hit-to-keep-doctors-and-drug-companies-rich): *The Washington Post Wants Seniors to Take a Hit*

> Given the combination of a dumbed down audience, a sock puppet media run by the 1% and a phalanx of economists and pundits who will not or cannot **speak up to the point** that the primary prey pursued is not the problem, it's easy for the dogs to attack the primary prey by exploiting the secondary prey …

[animonks](https://animonks.com/everybody-loves-it/) blog: *Write Your Script in The Right Way*

> For a proper engagement of the audience in your explainer video or the explainer script; it is highly essential to talk on what exactly your viewers want to know from your end. Because speaking something which is known to them is a waste. So, be straightforward and **speak up to the point** without wasting much of the time in other aspects like features, technology behind your product.

The expression is only gaining ground in recent times.